# Direct2D calling WM_PAINT repeatedly without calling BeginPaint and EndPaint in WM_PAINT?

Tags: c++, gdi, direct2d

I have been learning Direct2D for a while now and I have come across a problem from my point of view. Does *Direct2D* call `WM_PAINT` multiple times in one second? Because without using `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` in *GDI* `WM_PAINT` is called repeatedly. Is this what *Direct2D* does to animate things without a timer?

I know I can call the Direct2D drawing functions  in between `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` after calling `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` in `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` Does *Direct2D* have a solution for this problem? I mean atleast not related to *GDI (*ValidateRect forexample)*.* I just want to figure out why Direct2D doesn't handle this thing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe show some code? Direct2d does not "call" WM_PAINT - Windows sends these messages whenever it thinks the control/window needs to be repainted.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is sent by the system when window or part of the window is invalidated. `BeginPaint` or explicit `ValidateRect` are required to validate that part otherwise it will remain invalidated.

Comment: Just use official samples as starter projects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/simple-direct-2d-application/ you will see WM_PAINT is hardly used, mostly when the window (if there's a window) is resized. Please post a reproducible sample app https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @StefanFFM  I meant the Direct2D code just gets called inside WM_PAINT without calling some gdi functions to stop the rendering when its done

Comment: @SimonMourier So you mean there is no need to render with Direct2D inside WM_PAINT? So it works like something like GetDC?

Comment: @user7860670 I meant to say the Paint code just gets called inside WM_PAINT even after its done painting

Comment: If you don't call Begin/EndPaint yourself then you have to call [ValidateRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect) to tell the OS that the paint is done.

Comment: @HansPassant If this is the case, then why is WM_PAINT rarely used for rendering in SimonMourier's answer?

Comment: That's accurate.  But you still have a window and it behaves like a window.

Comment: You can draw Direct2D inside WM_PAINT or outside, but you must honor WM_PAINT the usual Windows way when asked for it (BeginPaint/EndPaint). Follow the samples.